# ¿Como cambiar el estilo de un elemento dentro de otro, usando pseudo-elementos para saber su estado?

Tags: html, css3, eventos

Mi idea es simple: Identificar el estado de un elemento y deacuerdo a ello cambiar el estilo de otro elemento:

Intento con esto y el elemento div dentro del div trespuntos no cambia y se queda invisible. ¿Como hago para que esto funcione?.

```css
/* El css: */
#trespuntos b:hover {
  display: none;
  #trespuntos div {
    display: block;
  }
}

#trespuntos b {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#trespuntos div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- El HTML: -->
<div id="trespuntos">Descripción:<b>...</b>
  <div>
    <h3>Beneficios:</h3>
    <ul>......</ul>
    <h3>Ploblemas:</h3>
    <ul>.......</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes explicar qué esperarías que pasara? El div interior siempre tiene display block

Comment: @ffflabs Se me paso el error.:) Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es sintácticamente correcto anidar selectores en CSS, como sí se puede hacer en supersets como LESS, SASS , Stylus y SCSS. Toda relación de cascadeo (la C de css) se expresa fuera de las llaves.

Si la expresión que pones fuera admisible, de todos modos estaría apuntando a `"un <div id='trespuntos'> dentro de un elemento <b> dentro de un <div id='trespuntos'>"`

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer dándole estilo a la secuencia:  `cuando se produzca un elemento X seguido de un elemento Y, dale este estilo`

```css
#trespuntos b{font-size:1.5em;}
#trespuntos div{display:none;}

#trespuntos b:hover+div{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="trespuntos">Descripción:<b> pon el mouse aquí!</b>
  <div>
     <h3>Beneficios:</h3>
      <ul>......</ul>
      <h3>Ploblemas:</h3>
      <ul>.......</ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Aunque en general las hojas de estilo operan del padre al hijo, ese es un ejemplo de estilos que se aplican entre siblings.

Comment: Muchas gracias. No sabia que podia hacer eso. Gracias.

Comment: Aprovechando. Conoces la forma de hacer que el código HTML pueda ejecutarse desde stark overflow en una pregunta.

Comment: Hay un botón en la barra del editor para insertar snippets. Acabo de editar tu pregunta para convertir el código en esto último

Comment: Es interesante. Lo buscaré. Gracias por la edicion se ve mejor la pregunta. Lo malo que no veo el boton de ejecutar, pero lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: Ya veo el boton de ejecutar.:) El ploblema se encontraba en la version de sitio que usaba. Tenia desabilitado el sitio completo.